# How to get file from AWS s3 buket using rest API call from simple HTML page

Tags: javascript, rest, amazon-s3

I have written a small code to get all file from AWS s3 but  i think i am missing somethting so i am getting

> **Error** : 403 forbidden.

In the below code i am generation signature for my account and also created time.

If any one have any other code sample please share. I read AWS-s3 documentation but i am not getting some of the points

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>fbjhbvaiu</title>
    <script src="./dist/forge.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var aws_access_key = 'aws_access_key';
var aws_secret_key = 'aws_secret_key';
var bucket = 'bucket_namr';
var region = 'us-east-1';
var keyPrefix = '';
var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
var successRedirect = 'www.google.com';
var kmsKeyArn = 'arn:aws:s3:::parse-html-code';

/*MY script........*/
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var currentDate1 = currentdate.getFullYear()+""                                                         
                  + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)+"" 
                    +currentdate.getDate()+""+"T"               
                  + (currentdate.getHours()+1)+""  
                  + currentdate.getMinutes()+""
                  + currentdate.getSeconds()+"Z";

var parsedDateTime1 = currentdate.getFullYear()+""  
                     +(currentdate.getMonth()+1)+"" 
                       +currentdate.getDate();

var expiration1 = currentdate.getFullYear()+"-"                                                 
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)+"-" 
                +currentdate.getDate()+""+"T"               
                + (currentdate.getHours()+1)+":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes()+":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds()+"Z";

var GMT = currentdate.getFullYear()+""                                  
                        + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)+"" 
            +currentdate.getDate()+""+"T"               
            +(currentdate.getHours()-5)+""
            +(currentdate.getMinutes()-30)+""
            +currentdate.getSeconds()+"Z";

function convertJsonToString(policy) {
  var encodedPolicy = forge.util.encode64(JSON.stringify(policy)); 
  return encodedPolicy;
};

function sign(key, msg) {
  var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
  hmac.start("sha256", key);
  hmac.update(msg);
  var digest = hmac.digest();
  return digest;
};



// Create string for X-Amz-Credential value
var credential = aws_access_key+ "/" + parsedDateTime1 + "/" + region + "/s3/aws4_request";

/* POLICY */
var json = { "expiration": expiration1,
"conditions": [
{"bucket": bucket},
["starts-with", "$key", keyPrefix],
{"acl": "public-read"},
{"success_action_redirect": successRedirect},
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", contentType],
{"x-amz-credential": credential},
{"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
{"x-amz-date": currentDate1},
{"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"},
{"x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": kmsKeyArn}
]
};

// Convert POLICY from JSON to String and Base64 encode it.
var stringToSign = convertJsonToString(json);
console.log('String To Sign: ' + stringToSign); // DEBUG

/* GENERATE THE SIGNATURE */
// Hash 1 - Key: AWS4ACCESSKEYID, Message: date
console.log('Generate dateKey...'); // DEBUG
var dateKey = sign("AWS4" + aws_secret_key, parsedDateTime1);

// Hash 2 - Key: dateKey, Message: region
console.log('Generate dateRegionKey...'); // DEBUG
var dateRegionKey = sign(dateKey, region);

// Hash 3 - Key: dateRegionKey, Message: "s3"
console.log('Generate dateRegionServiceKey...'); // DEBUG
var dateRegionServiceKey = sign(dateRegionKey, "s3");

// Hash 4 - Key: dateRegionServiceKey, Message: "aws4_request"
console.log('Generate signingKey...'); // DEBUG
var signingKey = sign(dateRegionServiceKey, "aws4_request");

// Hash 5 - Key: signingKey, Message: stringToSign

console.log('Generating signature...'); // DEBUG
var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
hmac.start("sha256", signingKey);
hmac.update(stringToSign);
var signature = hmac.digest().toHex();
console.log('Signature: ' + signature); // DEBUG

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/parse-html-code");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("host", "parse-html-code.s3.amazonaws.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-content-sha256", "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", GMT);
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJIIA5X7UFLLZ3RUA/"+parsedDateTime1+"/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature="+signature);

xhr.send(data);
console.log(xhr.responseText)

</script>

<h1>.................inspect it................</h1>



<p id="parsedDateTime1">
<script>
document.getElementById("parsedDateTime1").innerHTML = parsedDateTime1+"'''''''''''''parsedDateTime1'''''''''''''''''''";

</script>
</p>

<p id="expiration1">
<script>
    document.getElementById("expiration1").innerHTML = expiration1+"'''''''''''''expiration1'''''''''''''''''''";

</script>
</p>
<p id= "currentDate1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("currentDate1").innerHTML = currentDate1+"............My date nd time";
    </script>
</p>
<p id= "GMT">
    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("GMT").innerHTML = GMT+"............GMT";
    </script>
</p>


<p id= "hmac">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sign(key, msg) {
  var hmac = forge.hmac.create();

  hmac.start("sha256", key);
  hmac.update(msg);
  var digest = hmac.digest();
  document.getElementById("hmac").innerHTML = "";


    return digest ;


};  

    </script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do NOT ever ever ever send aws secret keys over the wire or put them on web pages. Just make the bucket publicly readable if you're not securing your key.  You're creating security vulnerabilities if that Keys IAM role ever gets messed up.  If you're doing this on a server, then just use the aws node sdk and use that to sign your requests.  If you're getting a 403 then either your key doesn't have the right permissions or you messed up the signature.

Comment: Thank for telling about secret key. But this code for only internal use. if you have any better code please share.

Comment: doesn't matter. the browser is always insecure even if this webpage is only available over intranet, it's shared by 1000's of other applications. DO NOT DO THIS. There is a reason the aws browser sdk doesn't support request signing, because this should NEVER BE DONE. use a server to generate pre signed URLs. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html